# mutt: save message to specific folder

Tags: mutt

I have several folders defined in Mutt:

```
mailboxes           "~/Mail/inbox"
mailboxes           "~/Mail/sent"
mailboxes           "~/Mail/archive"
```

I can save (move) a message to archive, by pressing `s` and then `?` to see a list of folders, and then I can choose `archive` from the list.

Since I always want only to save to `archive` I would like to have a macro, so that pressing `s` automatically saves selected message to `archive`, without asking me.

Can somebody please help?

**EDIT:**
I now have following macro, to save messages to my "archive" folder:

```
macro index,pager S "<tag-prefix><save-message>=archive<enter>\
  :set delete=yes<enter><sync-mailbox>:set delete=no<enter>"
```

the problem is, the messages stay in index marked as deleted. They are not "synced" immediately. Second, the `<enter>` at the end acts as `<display-message>`, so that when I press `S`, I end up in the pager of the current message.

In a similar way, I am trying to implement the `trash` folder in mutt. The following is taken from the [Mutt MacroSamples](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MacroSamples)

```
set maildir_trash=yes
set wait_key=no
folder-hook . 'bind index q quit'
folder-hook inbox 'macro index q ":unset maildir_trash;push \"T~D\\n<tag-prefix-cond>m=trash\\n<end-cond><quit>\"\n"'
```

but this does not work either. Insted mutt asks me:

```
Append messages to etmaildir_trash;push"T~D\n<tag-prefix-cond>m=trash\n<end-cond><quit>"/maildir_trash;push"T~D\n<tag-prefix-cond>m=trash\n<end-co ([yes]/no):
```

what ever I press, nothing happens
(the folders trash/{cur,new,tmp} do exist)

Comment: It's puzzling that `<sync-mailbox>` doesn't seem to do anything.  When you use the normal delete command (`d`) and messages are left in the index marked as deleted, what happens when you press `$` (which is the default binding for `<sync-mailbox>`)?

Comment: when I press `$` mutt asks me `Purge 1 deleted message?`. I can press `Y` which will delete the message.

Comment: A thought occurs: The `<sync-mailbox>` command is expecting user input (`y`), but seeing the immediately following `:` instead, so the purge doesn't happen.  I wonder what might happen if you put a `y` after it...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

tagged mails:

```
macro index S ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes\n<tag-prefix-cond><save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes\n"
```

current only:

```
macro index A ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes\n<save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes\n"
```

**edit**

```
macro index S ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes\n<tag-prefix><save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes\n"
```

My fault, using `tag-prefix` instead of `tag-prefix-cond`, will apply the macro to tagged messages if present, else to the current selected.

Comment: when I add your macro and start mutt and pres `S`, mutt says: `nothing to do`

Comment: Do you `t`ag some mail?

Comment: great, it works. How could I make it work on current message aswell (without having to tag it first) ?

Comment: @user1968963 see the update.

Comment: thanks a lot. Is it possible to combine it into one macro: If messages are tagged, act on tagged messages. Otherwise act on current message ?

Comment: @user1968963 maybe using tag-prefix-cond to set a different command/variable (for my understanding is executed only if there are tagged mail), I'll try but will require some time, will let you know.

Comment: I would very much appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

The [mutt guide has an example macro](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MacroSamples#poor-mans-trash-folder-management) for your use case:

> macro index <tag-prefix-cond><save-message>=foo<enter> "Save tagged messages (if any) to =foo"

You could implement it in your case like so:

```
macro index,pager A  "<save-message>=Mail/archive<enter>"  "mark message as Archived"
```

Hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> in either the index or pager view would save the message to your archive maildir.

Comment: there are two small problems with this solution: 1) I can only "save" one message at a time. I cannot tag several messages and save them all to archive. 2) when I "save" a message, it still appears in inbox marked  as deleted. Is it possible to apply the changes immediately (so that it is deleted immediately from inbox) ?

Comment: @user1968963 Answering 2) for future reference: <save-message>=Mail/archives<enter><enter><sync-mailbox><enter>