# mutt: macro for saving messages to a folder

Tags: mutt

This is an expansion on my previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102829/mutt-save-message-to-specific-folder).

I have following macro, which will save **tagged** messages to my `archive` folder.

```
macro  index  S  ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes\n<tag-prefix-cond><save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes\n"
```

and a second macro for doing the same action, but on the current message (not tagged):

```
macro index A ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes\n<save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes\n"
```

Is there a way to combine these two macros into one? I.e., I would like a macro that does following action when I press <kbd>S</kbd>:

```
a) in case any messages are tagged, move all of them to `archive`
b) in case no messages are tagged, move current message to archive
```

Comment: Have a look at [`$auto_tag`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#auto-tag).

Answer (score 6):

With help from Michael Kjörling, here is the macro I was looking for:

```
macro index s ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes auto_tag=yes\n<save-message>=archive\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes\n"
```